# Git remote and push refspecs

Tags: git

Git provides "git remote add" subcommand to create a new remote, and with it, in the config file, there is the "fetch = " parameter. This is a situation where I work on the same git repos in 2 or more machines, and I want to be able to transfer changes from one machine to another. So on `machine1`, I will set up a remote to `machine2` like this:

```
$ git remote add machine2 ssh://user@machine2/home/user/codes/mywork
```

This is the status after that remote creation:

```
$ git remote -v
machine2    ssh://user@machine2/home/user/codes/mywork (fetch)
machine2    ssh://user@machine2/home/user/codes/mywork (push)
```

and the snippet of `.git/config` for that repo:

```
[remote "machine2"]
    url = ssh://user@machine2/home/user/codes/mywork
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/machine2/*
```

It does not come with a push-specific refspec. I ended up having to manually add the following one extra line in `.git/config` as a follow-up to the `git remote add` command:

```
    push = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/machine1/*
```

So `git push` from my current machine (`machine1`) will put all the revisions on a remote branch called "`machine1`" on the `machine2`'s repo.

**Here's the question:** Is there a way to create this push refspec automatically or using command-line without having to edit `.git/config` manually? I wonder if the Git workflow that I have been using above is not that common anymore, because github or gitlab really becomes the way people do development across machines.

Comment: `git config` can add or replace any entry, but pushing *to* `refs/remotes/` is rarely a good idea. Usually it's better to have a mirror repository for local transfers. In your particular case, the way you use it can work (as long as the receiving Git doesn't reject attempts to set these references—GitHub would reject them, I think, for instance).